# TYPO3 9 tx-news wrong news in detail view

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

We have a TYPO3 9 installation serving a lot of different sites.

Each site has individual news records stored. But we observed that the news detail view could show the wrong news. Site A shows the news record of site B, if both records have the same path_segment.

In the news extension is a TCA Override that sets the path_segment to uniqueInSite for TYPO3 >= 9.2.

Do i miss something? Maybe in the route enhancers for news? Or could this be a Bug?

tx-news version 7.2.0

Comment: After further research, it looks like this:

In a multi-site setup, tx_news records can still be used globally. Since the path_segment is defined as uniqueInSite, identical path_segments can occur. If you then use the path_segment in the RouteEnhancers as identification characteristic, you will have problems.

So you have to change the RouteEnhancer and use the uid for identification, e.g. a `PersistedPatternMapper` with _{path_segment}-{uid}_.

Or is there a possibility to define a slug as unique in the TCA? The Documentation only lists uniqueInSite and UniqueInPid for evaluation.